# How not to display Cursor in a read only input type text box in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, onfocus

I'm using `Mozlla Firefox vesrion  24.01`.

I've a `text box` input field in my form whics is **read only**. In Mozilla, I could see a cursor blinking inside textbox when pointing to that text box, but in Chrome, it is not.

Is there any way to not to have cursor shown in Mozilla also?

I've searched for it a lot, and have seen some answers regarding this like to put

> onfocus="this.blur();"

as inline inside the input field. But, this works in HTML. When I tried with Rails `text_field_tag` it is not taking the method '`onfocus`'. So, either please suggest me a better solution to hide the cursor or tell me how I can achieve it with `text_field_tag` and `onfocus` event.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: How about cursor:none in css?

Comment: @Banana: Not working.

Comment: You could use `pointer-events:none;` (http://jsfiddle.net/VZ8xf/) – but that will also disable the user from every other mouse interaction with the field, like marking text for copy&paste …

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks. Is it a cross-browser fix?

Comment: You didn’t say this was a cross-browser issue? `pointer-events:none` has quite good [cross-browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility), at least for desktop browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion from CBroe worked. But, in a Rails way,

```
<%= text_field_tag "answer_name",truncate(answer.name,:length=>35), :onfocus => "this.blur();", :style=>"cursor:default;", :readonly => true%>
```

It worked. Don't forget to put the CSS line '**cursor: default;**' will change the pointer to arrow type as by default, a text box will have text-mode pointer (The pointer type that you can see while putting answer in SO through this area).

This won't work in `IE`. So, better replace the `text_field` with `div` element and make the text_field a `hidden field` to carry out the opeartions.

Thank you all. :)